# What are the leading bytes before the USB setup

Tags: usb

While tracing the USB using a Beagle 12, I am sometimes finding bytes prior to the transaction start. It is not the 8/32 bit SYNC, it does not start with a PID (e.g. 0x12 is 00010010b and a PID is ABCDa̅b̅c̅d̅) I am having troubl digesting section 8 of the USB 2.0 SPEC, and section 9 does not seem to address data prior to the PID.

[image]

What are these bytes for?

```
12 01 00 02 00 00 00 20
E6 04 16 51 04 03 01 02
00 01
```

Setup transaction:

```
80 06 00 01 00 00 40 00
```

Setup packet:

```
2D 00 10
```

get device descriptor:

```
C3 80 06 00 01 00 00 40
00 DD 94
```

ACK:

```
D2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These bytes are the descriptor data returned by your device in response to GET_DESCRIPTOR request. These data can't appear before the start of control transfer, something is missing in your observation.

The host must start with SETUP transaction [2D]. Then the setup data should follow:

[C3] is DATA0 token, [80 06 00 01 00 00 40 00] is "get descriptor", [DD 94] is CRC16.

This SETUP token must have ACK from your device.

The host then should proceed with IN token.

The device, in response to IN token [69], should always return the result, which is [12 01 00 02 ........]

"12" means that the descriptor contains 18 bytes of data. The rest you would need to decode, preferably using a better tool, like Teledyne-LeCroy/CATC decoder.

In particular, bytes[8..9] [E6 04] mean the Vendor ID = 0x04E6 (
SCM Microsystems), the next 2 bytes [16..51] means PID=0x5116 - product iD (SCR3310 SmartCard Reader), the rest are other standard fields of your device descriptor.

[D2] is ACK, which is good.

Here is an example of GET_DESCRIPTOR transfer from a LS mouse:

[image]

The descriptor data (18 bytes) are split by host into 3 transactions, because of max_packet_size is 8 bytes only for this particular device (Logitech mouse). The whole transfer also has several NAKed transactions, which are hidden.

Comment: I think the Total Phase Data Center is lying to me - for my convenience. It is taking the data payload from the DATA1 #14 response and putting it 'as a summary' in the byte dump for the overall Get Device Descriptor #6 as well as #11 IN transaction

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation on https://store.teledynelecroy.com/collections/usb-solutions , but they are not cheap for my personal project.

Comment: @JasonPyeron, it looks like normal hierarchical representation of transactions, the trace display just shows naked data at the transaction level (line #11), and expands all data after expansion the transaction into packet level, where all tokens are shown (lines 13, 14, 15). So everything is correct.